# Swift Disadvantages Array of Any

Tags: swift

If I store a Tuple

```
var person = ("Steve", 22)
```

I cannot add more data easily into the structure.
However, if I use an array of Any

```
let steve: [Any] = ["Steve", 22]
```

I can easily add the elements.

Surely there are no real advantages to using a `Tuple` and we just always use an array of Any?

Comment: No, we almost never use an array of `Any`. If that is the name and age of a person, it is much better to use a struct and use an array of that struct instead.

Comment: Actually you should use neither. Person should be a struct with properties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Any` is weakly typed so you lose all of the static type checking guarantees that you get with strong types, including tuples.  In addition, you cannot index out of bounds at run time on a tuple like you can with an array since the compiler knows how many components there are and it will fail to compile, and since a tuple is basically an anonymous struct, you can also name the components to make them more meaningful, which you cannot do with an array.  You also pay a performance penalty for the array of `Any` since your data has to be boxed in the `Any` where as a tuple is just a struct and its components are not boxed.